# Material UI vertically align item grid at center of grandparent container grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following Grid component:

```
<Grid container height="100vh" direction="column">
  <Grid item alignSelf="flex-end">
    <Button variant="text">List Your Property</Button>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container item flex={1} justifyContent="center" alignContent="center">
    <Grid item> // vertically align this at center of grandparent grid
      <SearchBox />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>;
```

The Grid with the SearchBox component is aligned and justified at the center of its parent. How can I make it aligned and justified at the center of its grandparent grid?

Answer (score 0):

Grid item does provide the textAlign prop to align itself to be center of the its parent component which is grandparent component of SearchBar component

```html
<Grid item textAlign="center">
  <SearchBar />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: My bad, I meant vertically align it at the center of grandparent grid. Updated the question

Comment: You can try to add justifyContent="center" and alignItems="center" props for the outtest Grid which is the grandparent component.

Comment: No, that can't do that because that will center the first Grid as well which I want on top right

Comment: If you want the first Grid item on top right, you can do <Grid item textAlign="right" />